# Extracting sentences with key words in a flask app

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to extract sentences using words from the user input.
I've an `index.html` with the form and a `results.html` rendering the list of sentences.

So this is what I tried :

```py
/*all the imports (flask, re, nltk, etc.)*/

letexte = "Welcome In The Details
about
Well... pretty simple. Do you want to know the amount of paragraphs, sentences or words in a text? Do 
you want to know how many times a word or a sentences appear in your text? Or maybe the 10, 30 or 50 
words that appear the most ? It's all In The Details
just enter:
    
    the text you want to analyze.
    the word you want to have the number of appearition.
    and a title for researches."

input_two = "text"
    
lesphrases = re.findall(r"([^.]*?%s.*?\.)(?!\d)" % input_two, letexte)  
    
print(lesphrases)
```

Using `re.findall` returns an empty list `[]` (I don't why) and `nltk.sent_tokenize` works but there's some cases where the `\n` are included in the list of sentences and I want to avoid that.

In my case, I feel like `re.findall` is the right solution but there also is the problem of "Dr. name" so... I don't know.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using re, you could do something like this: `[i for i in letexte.split('.') if input_two in i]`.

If you want to avoid "\n", `[print(i) for i in letexte.split('.') if input_two in i]` to render "\n" as "new lines".

Otherwise this might help you:`[i.replace('\n', '') for i in letexte.split('.') if input_two in i]`.

Comment: is it possible to split with "?" and "!" too ?

Comment: If you want to have multiple delimiters, the easiest would be to use regex. For example, if you want to split on `?` or `!` or `.` do `[i for i in re.split('\? |\! |\. ', letexte) if input_two in i]`. ( the character \ tells regex to take this character literally. They are seen by the regex interpreter as special characters otherwise)